# where to put log4j.properties file for tomcat6 java apps?

Tags: java, tomcat, log4j

I'm trying to configure logging for a RESTful / jax-rs java app. The app functions correctly, but I can't get logging configured. in my code I have:

`private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Foo.class);
        static
        {
                PropertyConfigurator.configure("log4j.properties");
        }`

and i have put the usual log4j.properties in WebContent/WEB-INF/,
but when I start tomcat with this app, I get in catalina.out:

`log4j:ERROR Could not read configuration file [log4j.properties].
java.io.FileNotFoundException: log4j.properties (No such file or directory)`

where else can i possibly put the file? sorry if this is a n00b question, but this has been stumping me for a while.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Put it with your application code under /WEB-INF/classes, log4j expects to find it in the classpath. And you don't need to call the configurator, that happens automatically.

Comment: And don't manually call `PropertyConfigurator.configure()` It happens by itself.